# Can't use Guava Optional for default constructor?

Tags: java, guava

I can't figure out the proper way to have a default constructor argument that is an Guava Optional. The following code will not compile with Java 1.6

```
public class ShoppingCart implements Serializable {
private final Optional<DiscountCoupon> discountCoupon;

public ShoppingCart() {
    this(Optional.absent());
}
public ShoppingCart(Optional<DiscountCoupon> dc) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(dc);
    if (dc.isPresent()) {
        Preconditions.checkArgument(dc.get().getPennyDiscount() != 0 || 
                        dc.get().getPercentDiscount() != 0);
    }
    discountCoupon = dc;
}
```

Error reported is  is:

```
/Users/pfarrell/sandbox//com/wayfinderdigital/struct/ShoppingCart.java:29: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor ShoppingCart(com.google.common.base.Optional<java.lang.Object>)
location: class com.wayfinderdigital.struct.ShoppingCart
    this(Optional.absent());
```

Comment: Seems bizarre to have both `ShoppingCart()` and `ShoppingCart(Optional<X>)` as public constructors. Is there any clean way to change it to `ShoppingCart()` and `ShoppingCart(X)` while still using Optional internally? I guess the simplest approach is a private helper that takes Optional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java can't automatically infer the generics from the code you've written.  Instead, use

```
public ShoppingCart() {
  this(Optional.<DiscountCoupon>absent());
}
```

(Though I have to ask -- are you sure that `Optional` is really appropriate here?)

Comment: Thanks, I would never have guessed that the <DiscountCoupon> goes after the dot. Some parts of Java generics still baffle me.

Your questions is a good one. I grok that Optional is really for returned objects and not arguments. I'll have to think some one whether this is a good design.

Comment: Concerning generics, this helps me: You can have `Something<A>.<B>()`. The part before the dot goes to the type, the part after goes to the method. As the method is static, the type gets no type parameters here.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
this(Optional.absent());
```

to

```
this(Optional.<DiscountCoupon>absent());
```

The second uses an explicit type parameter specification, so doesn't require type parameter inference.  Type parameter inference can be done based on input parameters or based on the type to which an expression is being assigned, but many other site-of-use inferences don't work automatically so the type parameter assumes its lower bound.

Comment: I don't think the analogy you made is necessarily correct. The compiler is just unable to infer the generic type parameter of the method `absent()`, so it uses `<Object>`, but that's not synonymous to using a raw type.

Comment: Thanks. Sure would never have guessed to use Optional.<Foo>absent()

Comment: But Optional.absent() is static. Guess my real question is how do I tell from reading Javadocs that I need Optional.<Foo>absent() ????

Comment: @PaulBellora, I think you may be right that absent an explicit type parameter, inference is done.

Comment: @fishtoprecords, Javadoc won't help you except to help you figure out what needs type parameters.  You need to look at how you're calling the method.  Inference happens in two places -- based on parameters and in initializers.  `Optional.present(x)` works because the type parameter just takes the type of `x`, and `Optional<Foo> x = Optional.absent()` works, because the type parameters are assumed based on the type being initialized: `Optional<Foo>`.  Other kinds of inference don't work.